# Tkinter Checkbutton not updating for LED light control with PyMata

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, tkinter-button, firmata

Trying to get my GUI to communicate with `PyMata` to turn an LED off and on based on the check button.

The wiring and `PyMata` code is fine since I can get the LED to blink off and on again but I cant get the LED to turn off or on based on the checkbox
My checkbox has this as the code right now.

```
light_state = BooleanVar()
light = Checkbutton(window, text='LED Light', font = ("Times New Roman",10), var = light_state, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
```

and my pymata loop is

```
while True:
    window.update()
    if light_state==True:
        board.digital[pinLED].write(1)
    elif light_state==False:
        board.digital[pinLED].write(0)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

After setting print statements to see what was happening to the variable it kept printing PY_VAR0 which I found was cause the variable wouldn't update its self you had to get it using the .get command. My code turned into

```
while True:
    window.update()
    if light_state.get()==True:
        board.digital[pinLED].write(0)
    elif:
        board.digital[pinLED].write(1)
```

and all works well now, hopefully this helps someone else sometime